# Pandas: Tricky Unicode Bug when transforming Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unicode, special-characters

**Issue** Can't seem to remove a special char (�) from dataframe column.

**Background**: I've got a dataframe of stock price history downloaded from the web in utf8 encoding ([link to CSV).](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3rymKE_hTAmhKDL-7N79CGJiVsoLmoWyEKkzf_ibSU/edit?usp=sharing) I've attempted a `.apply()` on the column containing daily trading volumes, i.e., 'Volume'. As the screenshot below shows, the `.apply()` uses a lambda to first remove all commas from the string and then convert the result to `int`. When this lambda hits the � char....well, you can imagine.

Usually conversion from `str` to `int` or `float` in pandas is a cinch. I can't seem remove the issue after several hours of searching on SO and attempting solutions to convert / remove unicodes.

Ultimately, I want a function to remove ALL special chars / unicodes from strings or simply convert them to a utf8 equivalent and create a Boolean mask so I can avoid this problem in the future.

**Code**
[image: Err Report from Code]

Comment: Line 2093 in the CSV has garbage in it.  Fix the input, or sanitize it and check for an empty string before calling `int`.  Show a reproducible example and we could provide better advice.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That garbage is the stuff I was trying to get rid of. More importantly, I want to avoid all such garbage if it's introduced in any data coming from outside sources in the future. MaxU gave a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df.Volume = pd.to_numeric(df.Volume.str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the garbage in CSV line 2093, keep only digits and add an extra leading zero for empty string conditions:

```
lambda x: int('0'+re.sub('[^0-9]','',x))
```

Comment: `int('')` still raises.

Comment: int('�') and int('') both give ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the file for you and tried it out. This should work:

```
[re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','0', i.decode('utf-8').replace(',','')) for i in test.Volume]
```